# Get Value from parameter function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jira-rest-api

Sorry for the Noob Question. I'm trying to write a node.js function called "getTransitionId" that uses the [jira-connector](http://floralvikings.github.io/jira-connector/) plugin to retrieve data for possible transitions for a particular issue.

The getTransitions function from the jira-connector takes two parameters: an object with the parameters of the ticket, and a function to execute once the call is finished.

Here's my problem: for reasons beyond the scope of this question, I want to access this data outside the function that's being passed as parameter to "getTransitions." But I can't figure out how. I understand that the last return statement (return "transitionData") is returning "undefined" because it's executing a return statement before the call is finished, but I don't know how to fix that.

Can I correctly use a callback in this case? If so, how would I use it in a function that is being passed as a parameter to another function?

```
const JiraApi = require('jira-connector');

const jira = new JiraApi( {
    host: //Jira URL
    basic_auth: {
        //Authentication Information
    }
});


function getTransitionId (ticketNumber, transition) {
    jira.issue.getTransitions({
        issueKey: ticketNumber,
    }, function(error, transitions){
        const transitionData = transitions['transitions'];
    });

return transitionData;
}
```

Thanks for the help. Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your own `getTransitionId` function take a callback function as an argument. Here's an *incomplete* example (see ahead):

```
function getTransitionId (ticketNumber, transition, callback) {
    jira.issue.getTransitions({
        issueKey: ticketNumber,
    }, function(error, transitions){
        const transitionData = transitions['transitions'];
        const id = /* ..get ID fron transitionData, somehow.. */
        callback(id);
    });
}

// Called like this:
getTransitionId(ticketNumber, transition, function(id) {
    console.log("Got the ID:", id);
});
```

This isn't perfect, though. What if `getTransitions` has an error?

When you call `jira.issue.getTransitions`, you pass a callback function which takes *two* parameters: `error` and `transitions`. This is standard for functions which take callbacks in JavaScript - that is, callbacks usually take an error parameter (null or undefined if there was no error) and a data parameter (containing results of the action, like fetched `transitions` or an `id`).

We can change `getTransitionId` to take an error and then pass the error to the callback that you gave to `getTransitionId`:

```
function getTransitionId (ticketNumber, transition, callback) {
    jira.issue.getTransitions({
        issueKey: ticketNumber,
    }, function(error, transitions){
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
            return;
        }
        const transitionData = transitions['transitions'];
        const id = /* ..get ID fron transitionData, somehow.. */
        callback(null, id);
    });
}
```

(Note that we use a `return;` statement inside `if (error)` -- that's so that we don't continue and try to use the `transitions` argument, which is *probably* undefined, since there was an error in `jira.issue.getTransitions`. This also prevents `callback` from being called a second time.)

Since we've added an `error` argument, we need to change how we call `getTransitionId`:

```
getTransitionId(ticketNumber, transition, function(error, id) {
    if (error) {
        console.error("There was an error fetching the transition ID:", error);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Got the ID:", id);
}
```

(Since we do `callback(null, id);` in the code for `getTransitionId`, `error` will be `null`, so the code in `if (error) {` won't run. Of course, if there *is* an error, `if (error) {` *will* be run, and that's what we want!)

By adding code to handle `error`s passed to your callbacks, you make your code safer. Contrastingly, if you *ignore* `error`, you might end up having errors in your code that are hard to find - for example, you might have a TypeError because `transitions` is undefined, or see "Got the ID: undefined" in the log!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!